What is the preferred procedure and associated methods when using an unobserved components model?
Let me start off by saying that my statistical knowledge is quite limited. If you spot any errors in my way of thinking, or have any good beginner references for me to read more about the topic I am about to describe, please do let me know.
I have a database consisting of governance indicators from various sources on a per country per year basis (for those interested: the Worldwide Governance Indicators from the World Bank). I would like to group some of these indicators together and create a composite index. This requires assigning weights to the indicators. Given the various sources and differences in methodology, a principle component analysis seems less well suited. Instead, I thought of using a Unobserved Components Model (UCM) with a trend component, similar to the Worldwide Governance Indicators. This way, I can measure some latent notion of governance using the trend. However, since I am altering their procedure, I have to figure things out myself instead of being able to copy their steps.
I am therefore trying to figure out what steps to follow when creating this composite index. I have a general outline, but would like to know some more specific steps as well as the methods most suited to execute them

Normalise data: All data are normalised using a min-max method to a range of 0-1
Account for missing values: There are a lot of missing values, seeing as not all years and not all countries are measured consistently. I am strill trying to figure out how best to deal with this
Weighting and aggregation: To calculate the weights to be given to the values, I would like to use a UCM, which requires the associated parameters to be estimated. I have read I can either use MLE or Bayesian methods, but I do not know which is preferred in which situation
Computing a weighted average of the values for each country for each year, based on the weights determined by the UCM

This is all quite general still, and I would like to ask help in fleshing this procedure out. Moreover, if you are willing to be a sparring partner for me to ask some more general questions, that would be very much appreciated as well.
Thanks in advance!
